# How to create a button bar for displaying a row of buttons?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

```
class NewBar extends StatelessWidget{

 final MainAxisAlignment alignment;
 final List<Widget> children;
 final MainAxisSize mainAxisSize;

 const NewBar({
Key key,
this.alignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
this.mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
this.children: const <Widget>[],
}) : super(key: key);

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
final double paddingUnit = ButtonTheme.of(context).padding.horizontal / 
4.0;
return new Padding(
    padding: new EdgeInsets.symmetric(
        vertical: 2.0 * paddingUnit,
        horizontal: paddingUnit
    ),
    child: new Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: alignment,
        mainAxisSize: mainAxisSize,
        children: children.map<Widget>((Widget child) {
          return new Padding(
              padding: new EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: paddingUnit),
              child: child
          );
        }).toList()
    )
);
}
}
```

this is some of the code for the button bar only. It does not display anything though.
maybe i am putting the class at the wrong place or i should return something to the main app.
am new to flutter.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use [`ButtonBar`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ButtonBar-class.html) multi child layout widget.

Example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MaterialApp(
    title: 'title',
    home: new MyApp(),
  ));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      body: new Center(
        child: new ButtonBar(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, // this will take space as minimum as posible(to center)
          children: <Widget>[
            new RaisedButton(
              child: new Text('Hello'),
              onPressed: null,
            ),
            new RaisedButton(
              child: new Text('Hi'),
              onPressed: null,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Outcome:

[image]

Comment: child: ButtonBar   is declared as an error since it is 'not a function' so i declared it as    child: new ButtonBar    Now i have a red screen error 'Scaffold widgets require a MediaQuery widget ancestor'

Comment: add `new` keyword. But its not necessary if you update to Dart two

Comment: after adding the `new ` keyword and running app again i get the error  _Scaffold widgets require a MediaQuery ancestor. The specific Widget that could not find a MediaQuery ancestor was: Scaffold_

Comment: @KevinRobert You can solve this by having a MaterialApp widget in the root of your tree, for example `runApp(new MaterialApp(home:new HomePage()))`

Comment: Or I forgot to mention that. I wrote this in a another file. Thanks @aziza

Comment: ButtonBar becomes Column when it overflows

Answer (score 4):

As of 2021 I'd like to add a solution for a button bar that:

- Allows many lines and many buttons in each line.
- May resize buttons to fill all the available space.
- May distribute buttons with [minimum raggedness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_wrap_and_word_wrap#Minimum_raggedness).

The [ButtonBarSuper](https://pub.dev/packages/assorted_layout_widgets#buttonbarsuper) widget from my package [assorted_layout_widgets](https://pub.dev/packages/assorted_layout_widgets) allows these arrangements, depending on the `WrapType` and `WrapFit` parameters:

[image]

Usage example:

```dart
ButtonBarSuper(
   wrapType: wrapType,
   wrapFit: wrapFit,
   spacing: 2.0, // Horizontal spacing between buttons.
   lineSpacing: 10.0, // Vertical spacing between button lines.
   buttonHeight: 48,
   buttonMinWidth: 40,
   children: [
        RaisedButton(onPressed: () {...}, child: const Text('I am a blue button like you')),
        RaisedButton(onPressed: () {...}, child: const Text('Hey')),
        RaisedButton(onPressed: () {...}, child: const Text('I am a blue button, ok?')),
      ],
    );
  }
```